# Drawing in OpenGL using Number of Primitives on the GPU

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I have computed vertices and how they should connect to each other (Indices) using OpenCL and they are already in GPU. So, as I know it is possible to share these buffers with opengl. But to call glDrawElements, I need the number of primitives to be drawn which is currently on the gpu and I don't like to read these numbers from GPU because it will decrease my application performance, so I am looking for some draw call functions which I can specify the number of primitives by a variable which is currently on the GPU. Anyone knows about that?

Comment: I think you mean draw*Indirect

Comment: @ratchetfreak I found it! Should I delete my question?

Comment: or create an answer to help future people searching for a solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

draw*Indirect functions helped me to solve this problem. For my case because I had multiple indices array, `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` was more helpful.